# Create string - Remove outer quotes from squared brackets

Tags: r, json, string, list, payload

I need to create following string as payload:

```
    {"url":"http://google.com","number":["123"]}
```

When creating the string based on list (payload_2) I get the following result:

```
 {"url":"http://google.com","number":"[\"123\"]"}
```

**Question:**

How can I remove the outer quotation from square bracket (payload_2)?

**Attempts to solve the problem:**

```
# --------------------------------
# Payload from string (this works).
# --------------------------------

payload_1 <- "{\"url\":\"http://google.com\",\"number\":[\"123\"]}"

# --------------------
# Payload from list (does not work, quotations surrounding squared brackets, still there).
# --------------------

payload_2 <- list(
  "url" = "http://google.com",
  "number" = "[123]"
)

payload_2 <- toJSON(payload_2, auto_unbox = TRUE)  

cat(paste0("payload from string: ", payload_1, "\n"))
cat(paste0("payload from list:   ", payload_2))

# -----------------------------------------
# Test 1 - Using [noquote] - throws errors.
# -----------------------------------------

number <- "[\"123\"]"
number <- noquote(number)

payload_3 <- list(
  "url" = "http://google.com",
  "number" = number
)

payload_3 <- toJSON(payload_3, auto_unbox = TRUE)  

# Error: No method asJSON S3 class: noquote
```

**Results**

payload from string: {"url":"http://google.com","number":["123"]}

payload from list:   {"url":"http://google.com","number":"[\"123\"]"}

Payload_3: Error: No method asJSON S3 class: noquote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to use double quotes in a string in R, then don't use escapes for that but use single quotes to wrap the string:

```r
# These two are equivalent
number <- "[\"123\"]"
number <- '["123"]'
```

Also, when you include functions from packages, then let us know, what packages you are using, so that we don't have to guess. I'm guessing you are using `jsonlite::toJSON`. The reason that you are not getting your desired result is because `jsonlite::toJSON` is meant to give you valid JSON code and your desired output is not. If you really want that, then you will have to manually adapt it afterwards using string operations.

```r
payload_2 <- list(
  "url" = "http://google.com",
  "number" = "[123]"
)

payload_2 <- jsonlite::toJSON(payload_2, auto_unbox = TRUE)  

payload_2a <- stringr::str_replace(payload_2, '\\"\\[', '["')
payload_2a <- stringr::str_replace(payload_2a, '\\]\\"', '"]')
```